# Javascript not working in IE 11, but works on Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple page which reads an XML file in the HTML table. It works in Chrome and FF, but doesn't load the table in IE 11. Our users are still on Win7 at this time.

In Chrome and FF the table displays and even makes the background color yellow if the value is =>3.

When I entered this code into this site I discovered the following error:

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.**

Sorry, I'm just learning java script and don't know how to fix this issue.

Thanks so much for looking.

```js
    
<script language="JavaScript">

  document.write("<table>");
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<th>Time</th>");
  document.write("<th>Count</th>");
  document.write("</tr>");

  // Create a connection to the file.
  var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  // Define which file to open and
  // send the request.
  Connect.open("GET", "WebSchCallCount.xml", false);
  Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  Connect.send(null);
 
  // Place the response in an XML document.
  var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;

  // Place the root node in an element.
  var PuTime = TheDocument.childNodes[0];
  
  // Retrieve each PuTime in turn.
  for (var i = 0; i < PuTime.children.length; i++)
  {
   var Calls = PuTime.children[i];
      
   // Access each of the data values.
   var count = Calls.getElementsByTagName("count");
   var PickupTime = Calls.getElementsByTagName("PickupTime");

   // Write the data to the page. 
   document.write("<tr><td>");
   document.write(PickupTime[0].textContent.toString());
   document.write("</td><td>");   
   document.write(count[0].textContent.toString());
   document.write("</td></tr>");
  }

  var trTags = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 for (var i = 0; i < trTags.length; i++) {
  var tdSecondEl = trTags[i].children[1]; // starts with 0, so 3 is the 4th element
  if (tdSecondEl.innerText > 3) {
    tdSecondEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {tdSecondEl.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

</script>
```

```css
<style>
h3 {font-family: arial, sans-serif;}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px;
 data-monetary-amount^="2":after {color: red;}
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

</style>
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Time</th><th>Count</th></tr>
<tr><td>10:00:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>10:30:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>10:45:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>11:00:00</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>11:15:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>12:00:00</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>12:15:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>12:30:00</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>13:00:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>13:15:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>14:00:00</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>14:15:00</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>14:30:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>14:45:00</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>15:00:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>15:45:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>16:00:00</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: just... let IE11 slowly fade into nothing. Let's pretend it doesn't exist... there is no IE, there is no IE... anyhows, IE only has security support until October 14, 2025, since 2016 microsoft actively recommends using modern browser like edge, just, go with the flow and drop support for IE11.  Unless your audience is in afria/asia, then go ahead and support IE11

Comment: it shows the line number in your console error where there seems to be syntax error of unwanted "<" symbol, looks fine in IE11 for me - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XEQGrd

Comment: I can't find that '<' for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code runs in other browsers (iPhone/ipad too) I will blame it on IE and move on with my life.